# AttributeError: module 'numba.types' has no attribute 'Macro'

Tags: numba

Code is below:

```
with open('models/shap_explainer.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    explainer = pickle.load(f)
with open('models/adult_model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    adult_model = pickle.load(f)
```

Erro like this:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3264\2761765422.py in <module>
> 16     shap_values = pickle.load(f)
> 17 with open('models/shap_explainer.pkl', 'rb') as f:
> ---> 18     explainer = pickle.load(f)
> 19 with open('models/adult_model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
> 20     adult_model = pickle.load(f)
>
> D:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\iAI\lib\site-packages\numba\serialize.py in <module>
> 18 from types import FunctionType, ModuleType
> 19
> ---> 20 from . import bytecode, compiler
> 21
> 22
>
> D:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\iAI\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in <module>
> 9 from numba import (bytecode, interpreter, postproc, typing,  utils, config,
> 10                    errors,)
> ---> 11 from numba.targets import cpu, callconv
> 12 from numba.parfor import ParforDiagnostics
> 13 from numba.inline_closurecall import InlineClosureCallPass
>
> D:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\iAI\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\cpu.py in <module>
> 9 from numba import _dynfunc, config
> 10 from numba.callwrapper import PyCallWrapper
> ---> 11 from .base import BaseContext, PYOBJECT
> 12 from numba import utils, cgutils, types
> 13 from numba.utils import cached_property
>
> D:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\iAI\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\base.py in <module>
> 23                        builtin_registry, impl_ret_borrowed,
> 24                        RegistryLoader)
> ---> 25 from numba import datamodel
> 26
> 27 GENERIC_POINTER = Type.pointer(Type.int(8))
>
> D:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\iAI\lib\site-packages\numba\datamodel\_*init*_.py in <module>
> 2 from .packer import ArgPacker, DataPacker
> 3 from .registry import register_default, default_manager, register
> ----> 4 from .models import PrimitiveModel, CompositeModel, StructModel
>
> D:\Software\Anaconda3\envs\iAI\lib\site-packages\numba\datamodel\models.py in <module>
> 304 @register_default(types.ExceptionInstance)
> 305 @register_default(types.ExternalFunction)
> --> 306 @register_default(types.Macro)
> 307 @register_default(types.EnumClass)
> 308 @register_default(types.IntEnumClass)
>
> AttributeError: module 'numba.types' has no attribute 'Macro'

I have no idea with it , i have searched for the solution but found nothing about it.

Please help to load above 2 pkl file successfully

Comment: If you try to use such a code in a jitted Numba function, then you certainly need to read the documentation more carefully. Numba is not designed to execute such a thing. It is mainly designed to speed up Numpy based codes, not general-purpose Python code. If you want a general purpose-JIT, then you need to use another interpreter such as PyPy, but you will certainly get other issue: many packages does not support PyPy because people focus on mainly on the standard CPython interpreter. Anyway, I doubt PyPy could help here since it should be vectorized function, and even IO-bound ones...